# Snapshot a frequently changing file on linux

Tags: linux, snapshot

I have a file which is frequently rewritten by some application. The application runs and exits in a loop, so the file handle is released in short intervals. Is it possible to get a consistent snapshot copy of the whole file?

Comment: Does a missing/empty file upset the app or is the app able to completely re-write the entire file from scratch?

Comment: It is an image that is sequentially updated. So the app most likely reads the full file, and completely writes it afterwards. So if the file is taken away in the meantime, it would be recreated I guess. If however it would go away before reading, it would crash or recreate an empty image which would then replace the real one.

Comment: It is possible to snapshot the file by `mv`, but that would lead to the problems mentioned above. Maybe the file used for reading and for writing can be two different ones, so the file just written may be copied while writing just fast enough to be repoened for reading the next round. If there would be a special kind of fifo, that would dissect read and write access, one could maybe use `tee` to capture the output to two files and `cat` to present the process the last written file for reading.

Comment: These would likely require modifications inside the app's file descriptior operation as the file would no longer be a regular/single file. From outside I can only think about making the copy in the execution loop itself, right after one execution stops and before the other starts. Of course, if that loop is accessible and if the duration of the copy operation doesn't negatively impact the loop timing.